# How to add dimensions to an array as the result of multiplication in numpy?

Tags: numpy

I have a following numpy array:

```
a = np.array([[0, 1], [1, 0]])
```

What should I do with it to make it like this:

```
np.array([[[0, 0, 0], [255, 255, 255]], [[255, 255, 255], [0, 0, 0]]])
```

Each 0 is transformed to `[0, 0, 0]` and each 1 to `[255, 255, 255]`.

I have tried different ways of multiplication but it didn't help.

I need such transformation to be as fast as possible, because `a` is supposed to have million elements and I want to store them into an image, so I need to prepare raw data for `PIL.Image.fromarray`. I want exactly RGB format because after the transformation over `a` I add some colored extra pixels in certain coordinaes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With basic array indexing you can achieve what you want:

```
# Example input:
a = np.array([[0, 1], [1, 0]])             # Your index
x = np.array([[0, 0, 0], [255, 255, 255]]) # The mapped array 

# Get the result:
r = x[a]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could either replace each of the values with a `[[[256, 256, 256]]]` or `[[[0, 0, 0]]]`:

```py
np.where(a.reshape(*a.shape, 1), np.full([1, 1, 3], 255), np.full([1, 1, 3], 0))
```

Or repeat the entire array 3 times and then reshape accordingly:

```py
np.repeat(a * 255, 3).reshape(*a.shape, 3)
```